# Are templates the best option? If so, is this the correct syntax?

Tags: c++, templates

So I have this:

```
//base class
class InterfaceItem
{
public:
    //iterates through m_SubItems vector looking for an item with that name and
    //returns it
    InterfaceItem* GetSubItem(string Name);

private:
    vector<InterfaceItem*> m_SubItems;
}

//one of the classes that derive from InterfaceItem
class Window : public InterfaceItem
{
    //other functions
}
```

So if I do something like

```
Window ThisWindow; //pretend it is already initialized and has sub-items
ThisWindow.GetSubItems();
```

it will return an object of type InterfaceItem*, so I am not able to access any of the Window specific functions unless I do something like

```
Window* TempWindow = static_cast<Window*>(ThisWindow.GetSubItems());
```

What is the best solution for this? Is it to use a function template? If so, would this be the correct syntax?

```
class InterfaceItem
{
public:
    template<class Type*> Type* GetSubItem(string Name);

private:
    vector<InterfaceItem*> m_SubItems;
}
```

I've tried this and I got some WEIRD errors. Files that pretty had nothing to do with this started saying classes that were clearly #included didn't exist and some other weird stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `static_cast` on the calling side is actually a good way to go. You will need to call that `static_cast` somewhere. If you don't call it on the receiving side, you will need to call it inside the `GetSubItem`.

Even better way, if you have `RTTI` enabled and are OK with sacrificing a little bit of performance, is to use `dynamic_cast` instead. The difference is that `dynamic_cast` would only succeed if the value the `subItem` points to is in fact an instance of type `Window`, otherwise it will return `nullptr`. This way you can write:

```cpp
Window* TempWindow = dynamic_cast<Window*>(ThisWindow.GetSubItems());
if (nullptr != TempWindow) {
    // process the window
}
else { // that particular subitem is not a Window*
    // handle failure somehow
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! In the end I managed to use template functions. I found out the reason I was getting those absurdly strange errors was because I was using this syntax <class Type*>, where the "*" makes no sense. I just removed that part and it compiled correctly, after I changed the call I wanted to "(...)->template GetSub<Window>("name to look for").(rest of the code)".